# Transfer file among microservices

Tags: spring, rest, spring-boot, microservices

I have a chain of Microservices (Spring boot/cloud)[image]

UI allows user to download file from file storage, but response returns back throw all microservices. I dont want to download file on each microservice and upload it to next one when response.(I dont want to store in memory, it will cause OutOfmemory error)
Is it possible to return some stream?

Thanks

Comment: why don't you return a URL instead of file?

Comment: only first service available from internet

Comment: Why not download the file from the first service?

Comment: If you want to pass the data between multiple services before storing it that doesnt really make sense. If all services need access to the file you should have the first service upload it to file storage then have all other services have access to the file storage. Anything else doesn't really make sense in any scenario.

Answer (score 1):

I would pass back a file reference only (like a url) and only when you need it retrieve the actual file.

So if the Client UI requires an actual file from MicroService 1 I would pass the reference back to MicroService 1 and let that service get the file content and send it to the client.

If the client can resolve a URL/reference itself you could even do with just returning that to the client and then letting the client retrieve the file.

Either way you want to minimize the moving/loading of the file and basically do this at the last possible moment.